# Changing the last element in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to invert a list of lists so that the values stored at the indexes in the source list become the indexes in the new list at which the original index would now be the stored value.

For example, one of the lists [0,2,4,3,1] would become [0,4,1,3,2].

However, I don't know how to modify the last element in the list. Here is what I have so far:

```
def invertLists(Lists):

  invLists = Lists

  testIndex = 2
  print("List before: ", Lists[testIndex], "... length: ", len(Lists[testIndex]), '\n')

  for i in range(1, len(Lists)):
      for j in range(1, len(Lists[i])):
          newIndex = Lists[i][j]
          if(newIndex == len(Lists[i])):
              newIndex = -1
          else:
              invLists[i][newIndex] = j
          if i == testIndex:
              print("Insert ", j, " at index ", newIndex)
              print("List so far: ", invLists[i], '\n')

  return invLists
```

When Lists = [[], [0, 1, 4, 3, 2], [0, 2, 4, 3, 1], [0, 3, 2, 1, 4], [0, 1, 4, 3, 2]], the output is as follows:

```
List before:  [0, 2, 4, 3, 1] ... length:  5 

Insert  1  at index  2
List so far:  [0, 2, 1, 3, 1] 

Insert  2  at index  1 ##(should be index 4)##
List so far:  [0, 2, 1, 3, 1] 

Insert  3  at index  3
List so far:  [0, 2, 1, 3, 1] 

Insert  4  at index  1
List so far:  [0, 4, 1, 3, 1] 

(Every list):
[[], [0, 1, 4, 3, 2], [0, 4, 1, 3, 1], [0, 3, 2, 1, 4], [0, 1, 4, 3, 2]]
```

One thing to note is that 2 is inserted at invLists[1] rather than invLists[4]. As I understand it, using -1 as an index should return the last item in the list, so I don't understand why it isn't doing that here. Excluding the conditional statement in which newIndex is set to -1 produces the same result.

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(Lists)):
    item = [-1] * len(Lists[i])
    for j in range(len(Lists[i])):
        item[Lists[i][j]] = j
    Lists[i] = item
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your loop ranges:

```
for i in range(1, len(Lists)):
    for j in range(1, len(Lists[i])):
```

Python structures are zero-indexed.  Typical iteration is

```
for i in range(len(Lists)):
```

or

```
for idx, elem in enumerate(Lists):
```

Your critical problem is that for a loop of length N, you're handling only `N-1` elements.

This is a far simpler transformation for any such list, `my_list`:

```
[my_list.index(i) for i in range(len(my_list))]
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried that before. If I add one to the range of each of the loops, the last index in a given list is out of range.

Comment: Since you haven't posted the code adapted for running the full loop, we can't fix it.  That's a separate problem.  You have to coordinate the loop variables.  Simply adding one to the loop header often won't solve the problem; you need a clean search algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems with your code. A minor problem is the index but the bigger problem that goes under the covers is shallow copy vs deep copy. When you do

```
invLists = Lists
```

Thats shallow copy and any change that you do to invLists will affect Lists as well. Thats the reason for 'Insert  2  at index  1 ##(should be index 4)##'

Python has copy module and you can do copy.deepcopy for nested lists. Here is my take by fixing your index & also you do not have to worry about last index as you are working on totally 2 different lists.

```
import copy
Lists = [[], [0, 1, 4, 3, 2], [0, 2, 4, 3, 1], [0, 3, 2, 1, 4], [0, 1, 4, 3, 2]]
def invertLists(Lists):

  invLists = copy.deepcopy(Lists)

  testIndex = 2
  print("List before: ", Lists[testIndex], "... length: ", len(Lists[testIndex]), '\n')

  for i in range(len(Lists)):
      for j in range(len(Lists[i])):
          newIndex = Lists[i][j]
          invLists[i][newIndex] = j
          if i == testIndex:
              print("Insert ", j, " at index ", newIndex)
              print("List so far: ", invLists[i], '\n')

  return invLists

invertLists(Lists)
```